# Limitations for workspaces in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, limitations

I have installed the Geoserver 2.14.2. I need to know whether there is any limitations in terms of the number of workspaces that could be added to a geoserver instance.

If so, what is the constraint limit?

Answer (score 5):

Since by default workspaces are implemented as directories on the disk the only limitation I can think of would be how may directories your operating system can handle (on the order of 3 billion).